# The fastest way to draw polygons with python

Tags: python, performance, graphics, 2d

I haven't found any useful info around the web. Right now, I have a problem with graphics speed, so I want to know: which way to draw a polygon on the screen, probably even window, with python, is the fastest? I'm not interested in fast init, or x server use, just to draw.

Comment: crayon? maybe ;)

Comment: First, I'm not using Android, but Debian-powered raspbian Linux. Second, I just can't find how to use kivi: no apps or compilers found. If you're talking about output text colour, then I can't draw a polygon with it. If I'm too stupid to understand you, than explain. Hopefully, you are not talking about literally taking crayons and drawing.

Comment: @RedCricket - LOL, Any particular color the fastest ?

Comment: @RobC I think mauve has the most ram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is contour drawing of openCV (https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html)